# What permissions are needed to renew memberships in back-end?

Tags: civimember, renewals

Up until sometime this spring 2020, non-admin users were able to [manually renew memberships](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/renewals/#manually-renewing-a-membership-for-a-single-contact) in the back-end.

Now that is not the case, see below. There is no edit or renew links.
[image]

For an admin it looks like this:
[image]

I assume a Civi upgrade effected this. The site is on 5.28.3.

We are using [Activity Type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension but that was added well prior to this issue coming up. Related member permissions I have for non-admin user level is:

- access_civimember
- edit_memberships
- add_activities_of_type_membership_renewal
- edit_activities_of_type_membership_renewal
- view_activities_of_type_membership_renewal
- add_activities_of_type_membership_signup
- edit_activities_of_type_membership_signup
- view_activities_of_type_membership_signup

Comment: there has been an issue with some themes that means the 'more' bit is invisible. not sure if that might be a case in your situation, but if you are using eg Shoreditch do you want to disable and try again? may not be the issue at all but it has tripped a few of our sites up

Comment: We are using CiviCRM Admin Utilities and deactivating did not resolve

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you need *edit_memberships* to renew in the back-end out of the box, if you have [Enable Access Control by Financial Type](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#financial-type-permissions) turned on you must then grant the corresponding financial types permission(s) that are used for your membership(s). e.g. *edit_contributions_of_type_member_dues*.